# PHP-FPM browser returning empty response

Tags: php, ubuntu, fastcgi, lighttpd, fpm

I recently reconfigured my server to use Lighttpd+PHP5-FPM. I have almost the same configuration on my localhost (using CGI on Windows, while ubuntu on the server). I have an AJAX request to a page that usually takes around 1.5 minutes, on server I keep receiving "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" while the same script (same arguments etc) gives the expected JSON response.

The php timeout is set, no error is given, on Lighty debug log I can see that after the expected time the response is given, but the browser stops after 1 minute, 30 seconds before the real response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using ELB from AWS, it has a timeout of 60 seconds. I found out that it can be requested to update the timeout to up to 17 minutes, but there is no way to do that directly on manager console.

<sup>Source: [Elastic Load Balancer: HTTP Connections time out after 60 seconds](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=33427&start=0&tstart=0).</sup>